# Como ter sessões simultaneas node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá criei um servidor node de CRUD basico usando o Postgres do Heroku e Mysql, o problema é que ele só permite que crie uma sessão, ou seja se você loga em um dispositivos todos que entram no site são logados também. Como resolver isso e se me indicarem uma biblioteca poderiam me explicar como ela funciona?

```
    const express = require('express');
const session = require('cookie-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')


app.use(express.json())
app.use(session({
      secret:'wtsrtsgt1234@3#22',

})
       )

app.use(bodyParser.json());      
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL,{
    dialect: 'postgres',
    protocol: 'postgres',
    port:5432
})


/*
const sequelize = new Sequelize('player','root','',{
    host:'localhost',
    dialect:'mysql'
})
*/

const Usuarios = sequelize.define('usuarios',{
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    senha:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    nivel:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
})
let sess;



app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    Usuarios.sync({force:true})
    if(sess == undefined){
        res.sendfile(__dirname+"/public/login.html")
    }
    else{
        res.send("YOU ARE A COMMUM USER")
    }

})

app.post('/login', async (req,res)=>{
    let email = req.body.email;
    let senha = req.body.senha;
    if(email == "empty" || senha == "empty"){
        res.json({"MENSAGEM":"Algum campo está vazio"})
    }
    else{
        const retorno = await Usuarios.findOne({ where: { email: email, senha:senha } })
            if(retorno == null){
                res.json({"MENSAGEM":"Não existe essa conta"})
             }
            else{
                res.json({"MENSAGEM":"Logado"})
                sess = req.session
                sess.nivel = retorno.nivel
             }

    }




})
app.get('/a', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('pock')
})
app.post('/registre', async (req,res)=>{
    let email = req.body.email
    let senha = req.body.senha
    let confirm = req.body.confirm

    if(senha != confirm && senha != "empty"){
        res.json({"MENSAGEM":"Senhas não batem"})
    }
    else if(senha == "empty" || confirm == "empty" || email == "empty"){
        console.log('ERRO:falta preencher um campo')
        res.json({"MENSAGEM":"Falta preencher um campo"})
    }
    else{
        const retorno = await Usuarios.findOne({ where: { email: email } })
        if(retorno == null){
            Usuarios.create({
                email: email,
                senha: senha,
                nivel: 'comum'
        })
        res.json({"MENSAGEM":"Conta criada"})
    }
        else{
            res.json({
                "MENSAGEM":"Esse email já existe"
            })
        }

    }

})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

Comment: Dê uma avaliada e veja se é o que procura: https://github.com/expressjs/session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente colocar o login da aplicação dentro de um "middleware"(uma função que é executada a cada requisição no seu servidor),por que talvez oque esteja logando seja sua aplicação inteira e não somente a requisição feita naquele momento.

O Node.js funciona com um loop infinito que recebe a requisição e gera uma resposta,utilize o processo de requisição e resposta para fazer o login.

Comment: É basicamente isso mesmo kkk depois de muito tempo quebrando a cabeça eu percebi que ao usar uma sessão global eu crio uma unica "sala" e então todos que entram acessam esta mesma "sala". Obrigado pela resposta